# Should I run my Monero Node on Linux, Windows or macOS / OS X?

Tags: full-node, windows, macos, linux

I am a complete novice when it comes to running Monero-related software, and have only used MyMomero and Exchanges thus far.

I now intend to dive into this area, and set up my own **Monero Node**.

As I do not have any spare computer I can use for this, I will have to acquire one first.

And now for the question; which **operation software** would be easiest to use when setting up a **Monero Node** for the first time?

**Linux**, **Windows** or **macOS / OS X**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run the provided binaries, it should be the same on all platforms, whereas if you plan to build from source, it's easier to use docker.
I find it easier to use docker on linux over windows because there is no need to add a port forwarding to the VM.

BTW, you don't need a dedicated hardware. Once the blockchain is fully synced, it doesn't consume much ressources.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest to use would probably be Windows, where all you need to do is download the .zip, extract it, and then run bitmonero.exe. It will take a little while to sync with the network on any OS (mostly depending on hard drive speed), but once it is synced, it uses only a small amount of resources.

If you intend to use the computer only for Monero, it is best to use the [Monerodo OS](http://nodebox.link/) which is a build of Ubuntu specialized for Monero.

Comment: If you are downloading the binaries, it's this simple regardless of OS. So for ease of use, the answer is basically use whatever you are comfortable with.